# Spring Roo Shell error - Unknown statement type

Tags: spring-roo

I have this error message in my spring roo shell:

```
     ____  ____  ____  
    / __ \/ __ \/ __ \ 
   / /_/ / / / / / / / 
  / _, _/ /_/ / /_/ /  
 /_/ |_|\____/\____/    1.2.5.RELEASE [rev 8341dc2]


Welcome to Spring Roo. For assistance press CTRL+SPACE or type "hint" then hit ENTER.
roo> Unknown statement type
```

If I modify for example a domain attribute it cannot generate/modify the corresponding roo generated AspectJ classes. What should I do?

**EDIT:**
I finally solved it. It was a random bug. I used this expression:

```
javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<String> code = root.get("bank").<String> get("code");
```

and the Roo could not process it. I dont know why, but without it its working. Any ideas why is that?

Comment: I use JDK 1.7 for compile.

Comment: I think it is the same. Or you mean Roo 1.2.5 Release?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the issue is thrown by the Java Parser, so try to change your code, for example:

```
javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<String> code;
Something<String> something;

something = root.get("bank");
code = something.get("code");
```

Or similiar